# Library Project - Updating the object when book is removed

Tags: javascript

**Problem:**

When the user creates a book, the information that is in the input fields will be displayed. There is a remove button that the user can click and it deletes the book. However, when I use filter() I'm just returning the book parameter, so what can I change about my deleteBook() to be able to delete a book? I don't want the UI to work but I just want the library array to update.

Repl: https://repl.it/@antgotfan/library

**What I've tried:**

I've tried manipulating the document and whenever the user clicked on the remove then it would be deleted but not update the object to show that it was actually deleted

```
// Variables
const addBook = document.querySelector("#add");
let library = [];

// Event Listeners
addBook.addEventListener("click", render);
document.addEventListener("click", deleteBook);


// Constructor
function Book(title, author, pages, isRead) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.isRead = isRead;
}

// Prototypes
Book.prototype.toggleIsRead = function() {
    if (this.isRead == "Read") {
        this.isRead = "Not read";
    } else {
        this.isRead = "Read";
    }
}

function deleteBook(event) {
    if (event.target.id == "remove") {
        library.filter(book => {
            return book;
        });
    }
}

// Functions
function addBookToLibrary() {
    let authorOfBook = document.querySelector("#author").value;
    let bookTitle = document.querySelector("#book-title").value;
    let numberOfPages = document.querySelector("#pages").value;
    let status = document.querySelector("#isRead").value;
    let newBook = new Book(bookTitle, authorOfBook, numberOfPages, status);

    library.push(newBook);

    return newBook;
}

function updateStatus() {

}

function emptyInputs() {
    const inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input"));
    inputs.forEach(input => input.value = "");
}

function render() {
    addBookToLibrary();
    emptyInputs();

    let newBook = library[library.length - 1];
    let table = document.querySelector("table");
    let createTr = document.createElement("tr");

    table.appendChild(createTr);
    createTr.innerHTML = `<td>${newBook.title}</td>
                        <td>${newBook.author}</td>
                        <td>${newBook.pages}</td>
                        <td><button class="table-buttons" id="not-read">${newBook.isRead}</button></td>
                        <td><button class="table-buttons" id="remove">Delete</button></td>`;
}
```

**Error messages:**

No errors but just not having an updated object to show what was kept or deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the books are in an array you can use a function that takes the book properties like author, title etc 
and then uses that info to find the book in the array and delete it.

```
let books = [{ title: "book1" }, { title: "book2" }];

console.log(books);
deleteBook("book2");
console.log(books);

function deleteBook(title) {
  let i = books.findIndex(b => b.title == title);
  books.splice(i, 1);
}

//Outputs 
[ { title: 'book1' }, { title: 'book2' } ] //before delete called
[ { title: 'book1' } ] //after delete called
```

Answer (score 1):

This soloution worked for me:

```
function deleteBook(event) {
  if (event.target.id == "remove") {
      const table = document.querySelector('table');
      const tr = event.target.parentNode.parentNode;
      table.removeChild(tr);
  }
}
```

Basically, you grab the table and then remove the child node that had the event fired on it.

You can grab the table using the querySelector() function, and you may want to consider giving that table a unique id or something down the line.

```
const table = document.querySelector('table');
```

Then, you take the target of the event, which is the `<button>` element, and get it's grandparent by calling parentNode twice. The first parent is the `<td>` element, the next one is the `<tr>` element, which is what we want to remove from the table.

```
const tr = event.target.parentNode.parentNode;
```

Finally, you can call removeChild() on the `<table>` element and have it remove the row that the button was pushed from.

```
table.removeChild(tr);
```